# nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'query' in

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a problem when I am doing an interface test
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException
I want to ask if these two files need to be modified,If there are other documents that need to be checked, I can also send them, thank you!
**ProductMapper.java**

```
List<Product> selectList(@Param("query") ProductListQuery query);
```

**ProductMapper.xml**

```
  <select id="selectList" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="com.fish.springboot.mall.model.query.ProductListQuery">
    select
    <include refid="Base_Column_List"/>
    from fish_mall_product
    <where>
      <if test="query.keyword != null">
        and name like #{query.keyword}
      </if>
      <if test="query.categoryIds != null">
        and category_id in
        <foreach collection="query.categoryIds" close=")" item="item" open="(" separator=",">
          #{item}
        </foreach>
      </if>
      and status = 1
    </where>
    order by update_time desc
  </select>
```

Comment: Assuming that `keyword` and `categoryIds` are the properties of `ProductListQuery`, you can remove `@Param` and reference the properties directly in the statement. i.e. you can write `keyword` instead of `query.keyword`.